# What is the meaning of "{plural verb} {plural noun phrase}" vs. "{plural verb} {singular noun phrase}"?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, objects

Do the following two sentences have the same meaning?

> 1. The robots perform their mission.
> 2. The robots perform their missions.

In grammar-wise, are both correct?

If not, what is the difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, robots have a single mission. In the second they have more than one.

Comment: ...and in the second, they can collaborate on multiple missions, or have independent missions, or some combination thereof.

Comment: I want to express a robot A performs mission A, a robot B performs mission B, ..., and a robot Z performs mission Z. In this case, the upper one is correct?

Comment: Is it fine if I ask one more thing?
I have robot A's location (x, y, z) and robot B's location (x', y', z').
In this case, which is correct?
'given the locations of two robots A and B' v.s. 'given the location of two robots A and B'

Comment: I am very sorry for asking this elementary question. Actually, in my country, we do not mind either using singular or plural, so this grammar is too hard to understand TT

Comment: @Danny_Kim That's similar: if robots A and B are in the same location, you say "the location". If they are in different locations, you say "the locations"!

Comment: @Danny_Kim, in the case of your second comment, I would suggest "Each robot performs its mission." This removes the ambiguity of potential shared mission and indicates the one-to-one relationship between robot and mission.